# JavaScript: How to get a string in HTML after processing it through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, download

What I'm trying to do is, the program takes an input from the user and then performs some calculations based on the input. The final result after these calculations would be a URL which contains a video which has to be downloaded.

The 'download' attribute in HTML is perfect for this and works, I've tried it by hardcoding some links, but, my real problem is how do I get the URL from JavaScript file after the result is ready and use the download attribute. What I'm ideally looking for is a way to get the URL in an HTML variable and then use the download attribute...

I've tried a lot of things, I've tried to send the URL to the HTML file so that it would be displayed to the user using `<p id="id"> </p>` and then tried to attach an onClick on this so that the download would start as soon as the user clicks on the link and so forth! All to no avail... Can someone help me, please?!

P.S. Today is my first day in JavaScript and Web development as a whole, so take it a bit easy on me (I'm an Android developer trying to learn web development!)

Comment: What is a "HTML variable"? Also, you'll have to post some actual code of things you tried, otherwise it will be impossible to know what you want.

Comment: Impossible to help you when you do not show the code. Show what you did that does not work.

Comment: I recommend that you should edit this question for clarity and also provide some code examples. It sounds to me that what you want to do is construct a url in javaScript, then make an 'a' tag with href set to that url, and also set the download attribute so it downloads when the user clicks the link? Easy enough, but I want to make sure I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

say you are taking a variable from user

var a = 1;

your base url is http://youtube.com, so do this

var baseurl = http://youtube.com;

after you calculation you parameter become 1abc, i am hardcoding here

so do this
var param = '1abc';

so basically to get final url, do this
var finalurl = baseurl+'/'+param;
or
var finalurl = baseurl+'/'+param.toString();

note here param is you calculated value.

Answer (score 0):

I guess these are the basics:

```js
// Grab user input with a prompt (or input box)
const input = prompt('Add something!');

// Do something with the input like create an href from the input
const href = `https://example.com/${input}`;

// Create an anchor, attach some text
const anchor = document.createElement('A');
anchor.textContent = 'Click me!';

// Set the download and href attributes
anchor.setAttribute('download', 'video.mkv');
anchor.setAttribute('href', href);

// Attach the anchor somewhere on the page
document.body.appendChild(anchor);
```